# Facebook long lived access token renewal

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have integrated facebook in my windows phone store app.

I am getting long lived access(60 days) token after login at first time.

I have seen over sites that short lived access token can only be extended, if we use long lived token for extend same will be returned.

But, I am able to get new accesstoken with new expiration time using my valid long_lived token

I used:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

How I am able to get new token.

Also, to get access token's info to get expiration time, I am not able to use:

```
GET /debug_token?
     input_token={input-token}&
     access_token={access-token}
```

I am getting this for debug:

```
{"error":{"message":"Unknown OAuth 2.0 method, debug_token.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}
```

Should we wait for access token to expire(in 60 days) and navigate user to login screen every time it expires to get new access token.

Please suggest about renewal of access token.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should we wait for access token to expire(in 60 days) and navigate user to login screen every time it expires to get new access token

Yes. If you were able to extend a long lived token without user interaction then it would be a token with infinite expiry which defeats the purpose of time bounded tokens.

In short, you cannot extend a long lived access token.

Comment: Ok. But I am getting new access token with the first link mentioned above. Whats that? I am saying about renew and not extend.

Comment: @vits you're trying to renew a long lived token so that it doesn't expire. Semantics aside you're try to extend the life of it. You need to wait until it expires carry the user through the login dialog for the short lived then extend to a long lived again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wanted to renew access token just before it expires so that user need do login every time, as I did in google with refresh token.Here, Are you saying we can not get remaining expiration time and thus can not renew? Means we have to navigate to login screen to renew access token. Am I right?

Comment: @vits correct that is how it is designed. Once the user hits your site you can redirect the user through the login flow, if no new permissions are requested the user will not see the login dialog as it will have redirected straight back to the site. You can see how this works using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and clicking "Get Access Token" and notice that the popup displays and closes right after.

Comment: Its ok if its by design, I will wonder if we can have mechanism of access token renewal say on 59th day for next 60 days and so on...

Comment: So the conclusion is I need not check for validation just need to handle any exception comes when I call any Graph Api and redirect user to login to get new access token, right?

Comment: Using the Javascript SDK or the oauth dialog you can refresh the token you have for that user more frequently, provided they're still logged into Facebook - there should be no direct user interaction needed - you don't need to wait for a token to expire to get a new one, provided your user is still logged in: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#refreshtokens